# How to use np.choice without memory allocation?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am looking for an equivalent of [np.choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) into an already existing array, so that I can just calculate numbers into some memory buffer in chunks, instead of allocating it.

Answer should be something like

```
import numpy as np


low, high = 0, 10
space = np.linspace(start=low, stop=high, num=1000)
rng = np.random.default_rng()
buffer = np.zeros((n,))
rng.choice(space, size=n, replace=False, target=buffer)
```

I expect buffer to have the data in the end, and not have more memory allocated.

Comment: What is the problem with the "something like" code you have shown?

Comment: @mkrieger1 `target` is not a keyword for `rng.choice` nor for `np.choice`. I am not aware of an alternative.

Comment: [`rng.choice()`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/914407d51b878bf7bf34dbd8dd72cc2dbc428673/numpy/random/_generator.pyx#L597-L600) is internally implemented as generating an array of indices and using `np.take()` against the original `space` on them. Maybe you can do the same.

Comment: ```np.random.Generator.shuffle``` modifies the order of the array in-place. ```buffer[:] = rng.choice(space, size=n, replace=False)``` will overwrite the memory in-place, but will probably allocate some memory internally.

Comment: ```rng.random(size=n, out=buffer)``` Is valid for specifying an output buffer. You can then do ```np.argsort``` on ```buffer``` and you will have random integers without replacement. But again, ```np.argsort``` will allocate some memory internally.

Comment: In general if a `numpy` method is compiled ('bultin') and doesn't provide an `out` parameter, you can't change the memory use.  Using `buffer[:]=choice(...)` is not an improvement over `buffer=choice(...)`.  It's hard to micro-manage buffer generation in `numpy`.